# Shorter way to assign a default value to the standard output stream

Tags: code-golf, tips, bash

I have this code :

```
tr ' ' '\n'|sort -n|head -1
```

The code is pretty simple, it takes a list of integer in the standard input stream (like `5 9 8 7 5 2 -12 -30`), it sort the integers and display only the first integer. But i need to ouput `0` if the given list is empty. And i can't find a short way to that. I have a solution with a ternary operator and a `echo 0`, but i feel i can do far better. I just need to replace the input stream by `0` if this stream is empty.

Sidenote : I don't need to call read to get the user input. The program is called with the input stream directly like `cmd < 1 5 6 -20 45`

Here my current code :

```
read l
[ -n "$l" ]&&echo $l|tr ' ' '\n'|sort -n|head -1||echo 0
```

Comment: @Pietu1998 i added my current code

Comment: In this case you can cheat by always outputting a `0` first, if leading zeroes are allowed.

Comment: @orlp nice thinking but sadly leading zeroes are not allowed

Comment: This looks like a programming problem to go on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure though; I haven't done any action on the question in terms of close/up/down voting.

Comment: @AlexL. *Make code X shorter* will be very poorly received on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Dennis That's for sure. But for one thing, this question isn't marked with the tag `code-golf`. Also, language-specific code-golf problems are generally not advised.

Comment: @AlexL. This isn't a code golf contest, it's a tips question, which is one of the [con-challenges that are considered on topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724).

Comment: @Dennis Whoops. Sorry for the confusion. I'm relatively new to the PPCG community and how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### <s>37</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
tr \  \\n|sort -n|sed s/^$/0/\;q
```

Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @DigitalTrauma.

Comment: `sed 1q` is one shorter than `head -1`.  Then you can combine the sed expressions to get 33 bytes: `tr \  \\n|sort -n|sed s/^$/0/\;1q`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Am I overlooking something or does `sed q` work?

Comment: yes - even better!

Comment: @DigitalTrauma @Neil The sed script can be shortened by 1 byte further using `/./q\;c\0` as long as the empty list doesn't contain white spaces.

Comment: `tr \  \\n` -> `fmt -1`

Answer (score 5):

## 34 bytes

```
a=($(tr \  \\n|sort -n))
echo $[a]
```

The first line saves the sorted input values in an array `a`.

This avoids using `head -1`, since referencing the array as `$a` will yield its first value.

The second line uses `a` in the [arithmetic expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) `$[a]`. In this context, an empty string is interpreted as **0**.

For a different default value, [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) could be used instead. For example, the last line could become

```
echo ${a:-puppies}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 42 bytes

Two different ways that have the same byte-count
Use `awk` as the last command

```
tr ' ' '\n'|sort -n|awk 'NR==1{print $1+0}'
```

Or do all the computations in `awk`

```
awk -v RS=" " '{m=m>$1?m:$1}END{print m+0}'
```

Comment: I could shrink the all in `awk` version by a couple bytes using `awk -v RS=" " '$1>m{m=$1}END{print m+0}'`, but then the two versions would have different byte-counts. :p

Answer (score 1):

## Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash): 41 bytes.

No requirement of any `tr`, `sort`, `head`...

```
t=${1:-0};for i;{ ((t=i<t?i:t));};echo $t
```

In a function you could use `local -i` for integer variables:

```
f() { local -i t=$1;for i;{ ((t=i<t?i:t));};echo $t;}
```

Then

```
f 5 9 8 7 5 2 -12 -30
-30

f
0
```

#### Note: If you **need** to read them from stdin

```
read l
f $l
```

will do the job.

As:

```
read l;for i in ${l:-0};{ ((t=i<t?i:t));};echo $t;}
```

### Another version 58 bytes.

Something longer, but could be quicker, as there is no loop.

```
. <(printf v[%d+99**9]=\  $@);v=(${!v[@]});echo $[v-99**9]
```

In a function:

```
f() { local v;. <(printf v[%d+99**9]=\  $@)
      v=(${!v[@]});echo $[v-99**9];}
```

Then

```
f 34 56 1000 12  -156 53 -12 -21 321 3221
-156

f
0
```